# Uploaded file with PHP cannot changed by FTP

Tags: php, upload, ftp, file-ownership

I have a script to upload files, after uploading file the owner of files are 48 (Apache) and when I trying to delete that files with FTP, I get the access denied error, the ftp owner id is 500.

I have CentOS without control panel, I install the apache and php and another things with yum command .

what should I do in apache and php configuration ?because I don't want change the owner of files each time manually .

Answer (score 1):

After uploading with PHP, do a `chmod("file.txt", 0777)`, which will make the file writable by all users (including your FTP account).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is owner of file (chown) the chmod function will change the attribute of file.

Comment: True, but with 0777 permissions, you will be able to write/delete this file from your FTP account, even when owned by other user.